# Why does the pET- expression vector contain a LacI gene additionally to the one in the genome?

Tags: molecular-biology, gene-expression, lab-techniques, biotechnology

The pET plasmid is used for protein expression with T7 promotor in expression strains, such as *E.coli* BL21(DE3)

It contains a lacI gene which codes for the lac repressor protein, a protein of interest under the control of a T7 promoter for T7 RNA polymerase and a lac operator which can block transcription, directly behind the promotor. The lac operon is another control of transcription of the protein of interest.

Furthermore, T7 polymerase is located in the genome as well under the control of the lac operon.

When IPTG is added, the lac repressor is inactivated -> T7 polymerase and therefore the protein of interest will be expressed.

The Lac I gene is already present in the genome of the expression strain used, why is it also cloned into the pET vectors?

Comment: Because you can then use this system in bacterial strains which do not have LacI.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @Chris. Are there strains that have the T7 RNA polymerase but do not have lacI? Or are those then just infected with T7 phage to express the protein? Could you find a reference for your statement and post it as an answer?

Comment: I don'T know about all strains - sorry. But you could co-express it from another plasmid.

Comment: Another possibility (and probably more likely) is that the construct is less leaky that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.genetik.uni-bayreuth.de/download/page_34/teach_85/Publikationsdateien/Themen_Schumann/19_GlascockGene223-221.pdf), a single *lacI* gene copy gives rise to about 10 copies of lacI protein per cell, and we can conclude, therefore, that this is the amount required to keep a single *lac* operon repressed.  The article also mentions the *lacI<sup>Q</sup>* mutation in the promoter of *lacI* that results in a ten-fold increase in the level of lacI protein.

If a *lac* expression construct is present at more than 100 copies per cell the result will be leaky repression, and this can result in selection for mutations in the gene of interest if it has deleterious effects on the host bacteria. The easiest way around this problem is to put a *lacI* (or *lacI<sup>Q</sup>*) gene on the expression plasmid so that repressor levels are commensurate with the number of copies of the *lac* operator, as in the pET vectors.